# Pinch Zoom in and Zoom Out in Objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, pinchzoom

How to integrate the pinch zoom and zoom out in our apps, i am using imageview on scrollView
 and my code is:

```
- (IBAction)handlePinchGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *) recognizer {
    if(zoomEnable == TRUE)
    {

        CGFloat factor = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *) recognizer scale];
        CGFloat lastScaleFactor = 1;

        //if the current factor is greater 1 --> zoom in
        if (factor > 1) {
            scrollView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(lastScaleFactor + (factor-1),lastScaleFactor + (factor-1));
            scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;

        } else {

            [UIView beginAnimations:@"animation" context:nil];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
            [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionNone forView:scrollView cache:NO];
            scrollView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1,1);     
            [UIView commitAnimations];

        }
        isScrollable = TRUE;
    }

}
```

Its start zooming every time from start i want if i zoom some then again it start when i stop zoom. Any help is highly Appreciated

Thanks;

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `UIGestureRecognizers`, if you're using `UIScrollView` already. `UIScrollView` supports pinch to zoom.

For zooming and panning to work, the delegate must implement both `viewForZoomingInScrollView:` and `scrollViewDidEndZooming:withView:atScale:`; in addition, the maximum (`maximumZoomScale`) and minimum (`minimumZoomScale`) zoom scale must be different.

Comment: thanks for quick turn around. i am using scrollview but i have three image object current, prev and next when i return any object in zooming delegate its zoomed multiple images.

Comment: Are you trying to implement an image browser like in the Photos app? Where you swipe to see the next image?

Comment: exactly..i am trying same as photo app.. any idea.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. There are several implementations of this feature on the web. Just search. Example: [MWPhotoBrowser](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser)

Comment: There's a class from WWDC 2010 which describes how to implement an iPhoto style photo browser. From 2012 there's a class that shows infinite scrolling. The 2011 is good too. You can access the videos by via develop.apple.com  (membership required).

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)zoomingImages{ 
    self.FullSizeScrollView.pagingEnabled =YES;
    NSMutableArray *_scrollArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    // add images to scroll array

        [_scrollArray addObject:self.image1];
        [_scrollArray addObject:self.image2];

    //now call init with frame function given below to set frame for each image in scroll view
    for(int i =0 ;i<[_scrollArray count];i++){
        ZoomingImageView *_imageScrollView = [[ZoomingImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i*320, 0, 320, 460)];
        _imageScrollView.captureView=self;      
        [self.checkFullSizeScrollView addSubview:_imageScrollView];
        [_imageScrollView release];
        self.checkFullSizeScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake((i*320)+320, 460);
    }

    [_scrollArray release];
}


@implementation ZoomingImageView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

      if (self) {

        self.maximumZoomScale = 4;
        self.minimumZoomScale = 1;     
        self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        self.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;
        self.delegate = self;
        self.bouncesZoom = NO;
        self.currentImageView.clipsToBounds=NO;
        self.contentMode =UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        UIImageView *zoomImageView_ =[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width, frame.size.height)];
        self.currentImageView = zoomImageView_;
        [zoomImageView_ release];
         self.currentImageView.contentMode =UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        self.currentImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        self.currentImageView.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;
        [self addSubview:self.currentImageView];}
return self;}
```